# sql caculating the 'x' businessday of the month

Tags: sql-server

if I wanted to write a query that said I want to know the 4th business day of the current month.  How would you do that?  I'm not sure where to start mainly because July 4th is messing me up...

Thanks!

Comment: Without a custom table with "non business day" (you may find something on the net with this) you won't be able to do that. I'm in Switzerland. I work on 4th of July. This is not universal ;)

Answer (score 2):

Most enterprises have an internal calendar which denotes the days that the organisation is working.  This'll typically exclude Saturdays, Sundays and any public holidays that the organisation chooses to observe.

My first piece of advice is to see if such a calendar is available for your use.  If it is, your query becomes trivial.

Assuming a table like so:-

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CalendarDays](
    [CalendarDayId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CalendarDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [IsWorkingDay] [bit] NOT NULL,
)
```

..your query becomes...

```
SELECT MIN(CalendarDate) FROM CalendarDays 
WHERE CalendarDate >= '2013-01-01' AND IsWorkingDay = 1
```

The good news is that even if your org doesn't have a calendar, you can **create one anyway**, filling it with your best understanding of what is and isn't a working day.

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop with some logic to increment the date by a day and check for week days and not holidays will do the trick.

```
BEGIN
-- some table with known holiday values
DECLARE @tblHolidays TABLE(holiday DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @tblHolidays(holiday) VALUES ('2013-7-4')
-- parameters
DECLARE @month DATETIME
DECLARE @businessDay INT
SET @month = '2013-7-1'
SET @businessDay = 5
-- logic, loop and find only business days
DECLARE @count INT
SET @count = 0
WHILE 1=1
    BEGIN
    IF DATENAME(weekday, @month) IN ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday')
     AND @month NOT IN (SELECT * FROM @tblHolidays)
        BEGIN SET @count = @count + 1 END
    IF @count < @businessDay
        BEGIN SET @month = @month + 1 END
        ELSE
        BEGIN BREAK END
    END
SELECT @month
END
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the below Query... it will help you....

```
DECLARE @startdate DATETIME 
DECLARE @count INT 
DECLARE @NDay INT 

SET @startdate='07/01/2013'  --Date of the month
SET @count=0 
set @NDay = 4 --Nth businessday

WHILE @count < @NDay 
  BEGIN 
      IF Datename(dw, @startdate) NOT IN ( 'Saturday', 'Sunday' ) 
        BEGIN 
            SET @startdate=Dateadd(dd, 1, @startdate) 
            SET @count=@count + 1 
        END 
      ELSE 
        BEGIN 
            SET @startdate=Dateadd(dd, 1, @startdate) 
        END 
  END 

SELECT @startdate - 1 'BussinessDay'
```

it results `2013-07-04 00:00:00.000` .... 4th Business working Day of July

Comment: This solution does not deal with public holidays. `2013-07-17` would be the **12th** business day for the question poster, as 4th July is a public holiday for him.